# How do I use a data parameter to set the colour of gnuplot points?

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I'm creating a GIF of the movement of random particles and I want to plot the particles as points of a certain colour that relates to the velocity of the particle at a given time. Using gnuplot 4.6.6, how do I make the colour of a point a function of a data value? If possible, I'd like the colours to come from the palette 'rgbformula 21,22,23' and not just from the standard line colours set.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lc palette` flag:

```
set palette rgbformulae 21,22,23
plot 'particles.dat' using 1:2:3 lc palette
```

type `? linecolor` or `? palette` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a third column to the plot command and `linecolor palette`. Then, the palette colors are used to encode the value of the third column and the colorbox showing the palette is drawn:

```
set palette rgbformula 21,22,23

plot "data" using 1:2:3 with points linecolor palette
```